# jquery changing values on change event for tags within the same table row

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table like:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="identifier" />
      </td>
      <td class="name">
        Some value
        <input type="hidden" value="Some value" class="hiddenName" />
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="identifier" />
      </td>
      <td class="name">
        Some value 2 
        <input type="hidden" value="Some value 2" class="hiddenName" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

What I want to do is that when an input with class identifier has its value changed I want to set the text in the column of class "name" in the same row to be changed to "Set value" and the hiddenName value to also be changed to "Set value"

So for example if the second row input with class identifier were changed I would want the markup to be changed to:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="identifier" />
      </td>
      <td class="name">
        Some value
        <input type="hidden value="Some value" class="hiddenName" />
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="identifier" />
      </td>
      <td class="name">
        Set value 
        <input type="hidden value="Set value" class="hiddenName" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So the jquery I came up with was:

```
$('.identifier').change(function () {

    var row = $(this).parent("tr");
    row.find('.hiddenName').val("Set value");
     row.find('.name').text("Set value");
});
```

However this is not working at all.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and how to fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.identifier').change(function () {
  var $td = $(this).parent().next(".name");
  $td.text("SetValue");
  $td.find(".hiddenName").val("SetValue");
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dqvHf/1).

**EDIT**: With your last update, the problem is that `parent` only travels a single level up the DOM tree, and from `input` to `td` to `tr`, there are two levels. Use `closest` instead, as proposed by @undefined, which will keep traveling up until it finds a match, and it should work, although the approach above is faster:

```
$('.identifier').change(function () {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    row.find('.hiddenName').val("Set value");
    row.find('.name').text("Set value");
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dqvHf/2/).

Comment: Actually wipes out the hidden field. I guess my method of setting the td text wasn't right. Probably should be innerText

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `closest()` method instead of the `parent`, also note that there is a syntax error in your code:

```
$('.identifier').change(function () {
   var row = $(this).closest("tr");
   row.find('.hiddenName').val("Set value");
   row.find('.name').text("Set value");
   // }  this bracket should be removed
});
```

Comment: @AnonyMouse Is there an element with class of `hiddenSpeciesName` in your markup?

Comment: Was another error. Have changed them so they match but still not working.

Comment: @AnonyMouse Do you see any error on the console? Have you put your codes inside the `$(document).ready`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this: **Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/f6WKF/

```
var row = $(this).parent().parent("tr");
```

and you have *syntax error* with the *quotes* as well,

Hope it fits your need! `:)`

**Code**

```
$('.identifier').keyup(function() {
    var row = $(this).parent().parent("tr");
    row.find('.hiddenName').val("Set value");
    row.find('.name').text("Set value");
});​
```

Comment: Why are you setting the text of a hidden field?

Comment: @João hiya bruv, Ah I copy pasted OPs code and in his/her code its `.val` and then `.text` on diff elements I just made it on same! `:)`

Comment: +1 good answer bro `:)`, _just a note_, one of the selectors should be `.name`.

Comment: @undefined saweet as bruv! oh cooleos, `:)` feel free to edit the post brother! < `you da man for edit` >

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using `parents()` instead of `parent()`:

```
​$('.identifier').change(function () {   
        var row = $(this).parents("tr");
        row.find('.name').text("Set value");
        row.find('.hiddenName').val("Set value");
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

Your getting an error because your missing a double quotation mark in your code ..

type="hidden value="

maybe this was the prob?

Comment: Fixed, but wasn't the problem